# Calculus of variations: two integrals

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I would like to find the extrema of the following integral with respect to $u\left(s\right)$:

$\int_0^T\exp\left\{\int_0^s\left[\frac{1}{2\gamma^2}\left(u\left(v\right)+\lambda+\left(1-\gamma\right)\frac{1-e^{-\kappa\left(s-v\right)}}{\kappa}\sigma\right)^2+\frac{1-\gamma}{2\gamma\theta}u\left(v\right)^2-\frac{1}{2\gamma}\left(u\left(v\right)+\lambda\right)^2\right] dv\right\}ds$

where $\gamma$, $\lambda$, $\kappa$, $\sigma$ and $\theta$ are constants. The Euler-Lagrange equation is unfortunately not directly applicable here; I also tried with substituting $w\left(s\right)\triangleq u\left(s\right)^2$, but it does not simplify things either. Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. OP's functional is on the form 
   $$ I[u;T]~:=~\int_0^T\! ds ~e[u;s], \tag{1} $$ 
   $$ e[u;s]~:=~\exp(S[u;s]), \tag{2} $$ 
   $$ S[u;s]~:=~\int_0^s \!dv~L(s,v,u(v)),\tag{3} $$
   for some function $L: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$.
2. Deduce that 
   $$\forall v\in[0,T]:~~
   \int_v^T\!ds ~e[u;s]\frac{\partial L(s,v,u(v))}{\partial u(v)}~=~0 \tag{4} $$ 
   is a necessary condition for a stationary solution $u(v)$.
3. In OP's case, the $L$ function is quadratic in $u$. By scaling the $u$ variable, we may assume that 
   $$L(s,v,u)~= \frac{1}{2}u^2+f(s,v)u+g(s,v),\tag{5}$$
   for some functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$.
4. The necessary condition (4) then becomes
   $$\forall v\in[0,T]:~~
    u(v)~=~-\frac{\int_v^T\!ds ~e[u;s] f(s,v)}{\int_v^T\!ds ~e[u;s]} .\tag{6}$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I followed your hints, and obtained that
$q\left(t\right)=-\frac{\theta}{\gamma+\theta}\left[\lambda+\frac{1-e^{-\kappa t}}{\kappa}\sigma\right]$.

This suggests that $u(s-t)=u(v)=-\frac{\theta}{\gamma+\theta}\left[\lambda+\frac{1-e^{-\kappa (s-v)}}{\kappa}\sigma\right]$

What I don't understand is that then $u$ is also a function of $s$, although it is supposed to be $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Can you please clarify this to me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I managed to deduce the condition you mentioned in the 2nd point, and I obtained that a necessary condition $\forall t\in[0,T]$ to minimize the functional in the original post is
$\int_t^T e^{\int_0^s\left[...expression \; within \; the \; exponential \; of \; original \; post ...\right] dv}\left\{\frac{\gamma+\theta}{\theta}u\left(t\right)+\lambda+\frac{1-e^{-\kappa\left(s-t\right)}}{\kappa}\sigma\right\}ds=0$
Do you agree that $u\left(t\right)$ cannot be expressed in closed form from the equation above? Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a perfect answer! I really appreciate it!